# How to quantify the "uniformity" of a distribution of holes in a surface

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algorithms, uniform-distribution

I want to try to quantify if the distribution of holes over a surface is uniform or not. The holes can have any given shape and can be arranged in any way over the surface.

Three examples are provided below:

[image: Three surfaces with the same area of holes]

Imagine that all the surfaces have the same length and height, and all the surfaces have the same total area of holes. One can argue that surfaces 1 and 2 have a much more uniform hole distribution than surface 3.

I'm having trouble however in finding a way to quantify this hypothetical "uniformity" parameter. I don't have enough knowledge of abstract math like topology and such (my background is engineering), so tackling this problem is difficult to me.

I'm a capable programer, and my idea is to build a MATLAB script to do quantify the uniformity of a given surface, following some yet unknown algorithm.

Does anyone know about this topic, or have any good sources I can consult?

Thank you.

Comment: Here's a matlab discussion for points (not regions/holes). It might get you started. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/180860-check-if-2d-points-are-evenly-distributed. For more help, try to tell us why you want to do this.

Comment: Are you only interested in the *shapes* of the holes, or are you also interested in their *placement*? For example: Do you consider Surface 1 and Surface 2 to have equally-uniform holes (equally-sized circles on each surface)?

Comment: I'm interested in both shape and placement. I would say that a surface with many small equally spaced holes is "more uniform" than a surface with few large equally spaced holes. I would also say that a surface with 20 unevenly distributed holes is "more non-uniform" than a surface with 20 evenly distributed holes (for holes of the same diameter). I'm interested in this problem because I need a way of distinguishing between permeable surfaces with equal permeabilities but different distributions of holes.